# Add Icon Button to TinyMCE (Plone)

Tags: tinymce, plone, genericsetup

I need to add a button to tinyMCEs toolbar. This button should include a icon:

```
<i class="icon-bogen"></i>
```

Textstyles are not working as the text would be placed inside the i element. The plan is to place the cursor somewhere in the text. By clicking on the new button the code snipped above should be inserted.

I want to use the tinymce.xml file in plones generic setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to create a TinyMCE plugin, take a look at this package which does a simple plugin: https://github.com/collective/collective.tinymceportlets

You should be able to follow how it's hooked up and how it works with Plone.